# How to update kubernetes deployment without updating image

Tags: kubernetes

Background.

We are using k8s 1.7. We use deployment.yml to maintain/update k8s cluster state. In deployment.yml, pod's image is set to `${some_image}:latest`. Once deployment is created, pod's image will update to `${some_image}:${build_num}`, whenever there is code merge into master.

What happen now is, let's say if we need to modified the resource limited in deployment.yml and re-apply it. The image of deployment will be updated to `${some_image} :latest` as well. We want to keep the image as it is in cluster state, without maintaining the actual tag in deployment.yml. We know that the replcas can be omitted in file, and it takes the value from cluster state by default.

Question,

On 1.7, the spec.template.spec.containers[0].image is required.

1. Is it possible to apply deployment.yml without updating the image to `${some_image}:latest` as well (an argument like `--ignore-image-change`, or a specific field in deployment.yml)? If so, how?

Also, I see the image is optional in [1.10 documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#container-v1-core).

2. Is it true? if so, since which version?

--- Updates ---

CI build and deploy new image on every merge into master. At deploy, CI run the command `kubectl set image deployment/app container=${some_image}:${build_num}` where `${build_num}` is the build number of the pipeline.

To apply deployment.yml, we run `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “specified by CI”? If I understand, you’re using the “latest” image tag to stay up to date, but sometimes you don’t want “latest” to pull the latest image? Why don’t you stick with a tag that works for your app and not worry about having the latest tag of an image?

Comment: Can you link to the docs that say the .spec.containers[].image field is optional?

Comment: We use CI to build and deploy image. At deploy, it run kubectl set image deployment/app container=image:tag, where the tag is the build number. It doesn't matter what it is in the deployment.yml, once it runs again, it updates the image of deployment. and 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#container-v1-core here it says This field is optional to allow higher level config management to default or.... This make me wonder if 1.10 make it optional just like the replicas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you aware of the [`repo.example.com/some-tag@sha256:...` syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#list-image-digests) for pulling images from docker registry? It is almost exactly designed to solve the problem you are describing.

---

*updated from a comment*:

You're solving the wrong problem; the file is only used to load content into the cluster -- from that moment forward, the authoritative copy of the metadata is in the cluster. The `kubectl patch` command can be a surgical way of changing some content without resorting to `sed` (or worse), but one should not try and maintain cluster state outside the cluster

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't how using digest to reference image can avoid updating image when update deployment with deployment.yml. Our CI build and deploy new image on every merge into master. Digest is always different. Also, to make this more interesting, for some reason, we have to use packer...

Comment: Your question is still very confusing, but if your objective is to update a `Deployment`, but to ensure that the *current* image remains remains in use, even for newly created Pods, then specifying the `@sha256` will **pin** that image in place, because no more images pushed to `:latest` will ever(?) have that same hash. I strongly, strongly, strongly agree with the other answer that `:latest` is bad news, but if your organization can't start using numbered images, then the sha256 is the best compromise

Comment: _we have to use packer_ "have to" is a very strong phrase there, and is almost certainly making whatever problem you have worse

Comment: we use deployment.yml to maintain the deployment. The image `:latest` in it is more like a placeholder (because of it is required). The image of deployment will be constantly updated by the CI to `:${build_num}`. Let's say if I need to modified only the resource limited in deployment.yml and apply it again. The image of deployment will be updated to tag `:latest` as well. We want to keep using the same tag without maintaining the actual tag in deployment.yml. You know, it is difficult to maintain the actual tag in deployment.yml, as we have 20+ build_num changed on one image per day.

Comment: I think I'm starting to catch on here: you somehow have a `deployment.yml` somewhere, and you want the **file** and the **cluster state** to be equal to one another?

Comment: Correct. I know the replcas can be omitted in **file**, and it take the value from **cluster state** by default. Wondering if there is a same thing for image. Or maybe an argument like `--ignore-image-change`, or a specific field in file, which will ignore the difference of image.

Comment: Then no, you're solving the wrong problem; the file is only used to load content into the cluster -- from that moment forward, the **authoritative** copy of the metadata is in the cluster. The `kubectl patch` can be a surgical way of changing some content without resorting to `sed` or worse, but one should not try and maintain cluster state outside the cluster

Comment: I think this is the answer I am looking for. Could you update your answer? I will accept it. Thanks so much.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but could you explain "but one should not try and maintain cluster state outside the cluster".. I'm not about to push changes to the cluster without some kind of trace of those changes, which I can manage very easily through versioned manifests. This seems to adhere to the philosophy of immutable infrastructure a lot better. Do you store your `kubectl patch` commands? How do you know what commands you ran? You rely entirely on the cluster to provide breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 0):

> However, in deployment.yml file, we specified the latest tag of the image, because it is impossible to keep this field up-to-date

- Using “:latest” tag is against best practices in Kubernetes deployments for a number of reasons - rollback and versioning being some of them. To properly resolve this you should maybe rethink you CI/CD pipeline approach. We use ci-pipeline or ci-job version to tag images for example.

> Is it possible to update deployment without updating the image to the file specified. If so, how?

- To update pod without changing the image you have some options, each with some constraints, and they all require some Ops gymnastics and introduce additional points of failure since it goes against recommended approach.
- k8s can pull the image from your **remote** registry (you must keep track of hashes since your latest is out of your direct control - potential issues here). You can check used hash on local docker registry of a node that pod is running from.
- k8s can pull the image from **local node** registry (you must ensure that on all potential nodes for running pods at “:latest” is on the same page in local registry for this to work - potential issues here). Once there, you can play with container’s imagePullPolicy such that when CI tool is deploying - it uses apply of yaml (in contrast to create) and sets image policu to Always, immediately folowing by apply of image policy of Never (also potential issue here), restricting pulling policy to already pulled image to local repository (as mentioned, potential issues here as well).
- Here is an excerpt from documentation about this approach: By default, the kubelet will try to pull each image from the specified registry. However, if the imagePullPolicy property of the container is set to IfNotPresent or Never, then a local image is used (preferentially or exclusively, respectively).
  If you want to rely on pre-pulled images as a substitute for registry authentication, you must ensure all nodes in the cluster have the same pre-pulled images.
- more about how k8s is handling images and why latest tagging can bite back is given here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to deal with complex syntax in deployment.yaml in CI, you have the option to use a template processor. For example [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.1.html). It would change the CI process a little bit:

1. update image version in template config (env1.yaml)
2. generate deployment.yaml from template deployment.mustache and env1.yaml
     `$ mustache env1.yml deployment.mustache > deployment.yaml`
3. apply configuration to cluster.
     `$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

The main benefits:

1. `env1.yaml` always contains the latest master build image, so you are creating the deployment object using correct image.
2. `env1.yaml` is easy to update or generate at the CI step.
3. `deployment.mustache` stays immutable, and you are sure that all that could possibly change in the final `deployment.yaml` is an image version.

There are many other template rendering solutions in case mustache doesn't fit well in your CI.

Answer (score 0):

Like Const above I highly recommend against using `:latest` in any docker image and instead use CI/CD to solve the version problem.

We have the same issue on the [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) project where we have many git repositories and as we change things like libraries or base docker images we need to change lots of versions in `pom.xml, package.json, Dockerfiles, helm charts` etc.

We use a simple CLI tool called [UpdateBot](https://github.com/jenkins-x/updatebot) which automates the generation of Pull Requests on all downstream repositories. We tend to think of this as Continuous Delivery for libraries and base images ;). e.g. here's the [current Pull Requests that UpdateBot has generated on the Jenkins X organisation repositories](https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Apr+archived%3Afalse+user%3Ajenkins-x+is%3Aclosed+label%3Aupdatebot)

Then here's how we update Dockerfiles / helm charts as we release, say, new base images:
https://github.com/jenkins-x/builder-base/blob/master/jx/scripts/release.sh#L28-L29